# Can this Stripe webhook error message be ignored

Tags: stripe

Stripe payments are working but this message is a concern.  Also shows failures on Stripe developer dashboad.

Is there a way to stop it?

Here is the message from Stripe:

```
Hi there,   

We’re still having trouble sending requests in live mode to a webhook endpoint associated with your XYZ account. Stripe sends webhook events to your server to notify you of activity in your Stripe account, such as a completed payout or a newly-created invoice.    


The URL of the failing webhook endpoint is: https://nb.abcdef.org/civicrm/payment/ipn/1
```

Comment: One-time payments will work without it but recurring won't. Is there any error in the civi log?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the webhooks from the stripe portal and create again from CiviCRM admin status page

Comment: Have done that multiple times.  The Stripe messages continue.

Comment: can you check webhook response on the stripe portal?